# Webpack.config not running Sass-Loader before PostCSS-Loader

Tags: css, sass, webpack, postcss

My config file currently has the following possibly relevant code:

```
  {
    // do not exclude `node_modules`
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
      'style-loader',
      'css',
      { publicPath: '../' }
    )
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
      'style-loader',
      ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      { publicPath: '../' }
    )
  },
```

It's important that I run sass-loader first because PostCSS-loader (Autoprefixer) is unable to reach code within a @mixin that I have.

So far I've been unable to apply the relevant vendor prefix to the @mixin code being imported in. Everything works as expected if I move the @mixin code to where I @include it.

Comment: Loaders act like functions, that's why it's from right to left. When you use this "style!css", imagine them like functions: style( css( file ) )... in this case css is called first.

Comment: Hi, yes I've tried reordering them as well as messing around with `postLoaders`. I'm on webpack 1.14.0. Please let me know what sort of information you would like! I will try my best to be thorough.

Comment: Read my updated edit. That should help you out a little more. Also, what is the issue with calling one over the other first? Your css and scss shouldnt have any issues for styling, no matter what order you really use...

Comment: I have `transform: translateY(-50%)` within a mixin. I need Sass-loader to run first as Autoprefixer is unable to add prefixes to code within mixins or includes.

Answer (score 3):

For **Webpack 1** the extract function is expecting two parameters.

The first parameter will be applied when you're not extracting css to a file (fallback).

The second parameter is a list of loaders separated by an exclamation mark `(!)` , these loaders are applied from right to left.

```
ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
  'style-loader',
  'css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader'
);
```

---

For **Webpack 2**:

The [ExtractTextPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-text-webpack-plugin#extract) is expecting a loader or an object.

```
ExtractTextPlugin.extract(options: loader | object)
```

Example:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
    loader: [
      "css-loader",
      "postcss-loader",
      "sass-loader"
    ]
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm on Webpack 1 and I matched my code to what you have in your first example. I've tested it and it still appears that CSS in my mixins are not getting reached by postcss/autoprefixer.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the issue in my code. My entry-point files, where the scss files were being imported, were importing as such:

`import styles from '!style-loader!css!sass!postcss-loader!./styles/styles.scss'`

This was overwriting the configurations in my webpack.config files, so I simply changed all my import lines to have the correct loader order.